# Undefined index using button's name attribute and post method

Tags: php

So, using PHP, I'm trying to make a simple poll for my website and I've hit a block which I can't seem to get around.

To explain this as short as possible, I've got a form, in which I'm displaying the values from the database, and it all works fine. Using a post method, I thought I'd submit the data to the next page, here's the troublesome code:

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='glasaj' value='Glasaj'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='rez' value='Rezultati'></td></tr>";
```

Basically, just two submit buttons in a form using a post method, so the problem occurs when I try to get the attribute names in the php file where the data is being submitted:

```
$glasanje = $_POST['glasaj'];
$rezultati = $_POST['rez'];
```

And the errors the PHP outputs are:

> Notice: Undefined index: glasaj in C:\wamp\www\WebProg\79_a.php on
>   line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: rez in C:\wamp\www\WebProg\79_a.php on line 8

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: ^ better yet, what does print_r($_POST) say :p

Comment: ^ better yet, what does `var_dump($_POST)` say :p

Comment: The same thing. Problem is in the index that I passed in the post method, which is undefined for some reason.

Comment: @karthikr it should be `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: You are saying the error on print_r or var_dump is that $_POST is not defined? I don't believe you (unless you are in a framework of some sort) :p

Comment: is your form type POST ?

Comment: What's the difference? I mean, echo, print_r, they all use the same 'glasaj' index and they're all going to output the same issue. What I'm wondering is, why it would do so, there seems to be some issue with submitting the data between the pages, the attribute name for the said button isn't being submitted to 79_a.php, right?

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag. This question has nothing to do with databases. "Index" in the error message refers to array keys, not database indexes.

Comment: are you submitting to the correct URL? can you post full form html so we see what is going on? Are you trying to access these variables inside a function that is used inside another function that gets submitted to?

Comment: <form name="forma" action="79_a.php" method="post">

That's the form tag with it's attributes.

Comment: I solved it, firstly, the problem was that it wasn't the name attribute that was being passed through, but it was the value of the buttons, so I just changed that up. But, as MattDiamant mentioned, I cannot have two submit buttons, so I just checked if they're clicked with isset method, and if they are, only then would I pass them the values. Here's the code bellow, if anyone's interested or ever bumps into this thread somehow with the same issue:

            if(isset($_POST['glasaj'])){
    $odgovor = $_POST['glasaj'];
   }
   if(isset($_POST['rez'])){
    $rezultati = $_POST['rez'];
   }

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure, because you didn't include your whole form, but this is my best guess:

You're using multiple `submit` buttons, and only the one you click on to submit the form will be included in your `POST`, and if you use another button to submit, then neither of them will be included. But, if you click `<input type='submit' name='glasaj' value='Glasaj'>`, you SHOULD see `glasaj => Glasaj` in your `$_POST` variable. If not, then we'll need more information about how you're submitting your form, and where you're trying to access these variables inside of `$_POST`.